# C How to open commands of abreviated documents in archives

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to open an archive named btc.csv, but my command is just "btc".
How do I turn the argument into the whole name?

**Command**

> main.c btc

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    FILE *csv;


    for(int i=1; i< argc; i++)
    {
    sprintf(csv, "%s.csv", argv[i]);
    }

        if((csv=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL  )
        {
            printf("not found csv\n");
            exit(1);
        }

fclose(csv);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to compile your code first, and read the [`sprintf` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf), that's not how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILE* csv; sprintf(csv...` ? No. Compiling with all warnings flag that as a problem.

You are on the right track. You need a string to hold the modified filename then pass that string to `fopen()`

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    FILE *csv;
    // TODO Use something other than a fixed size or at least make sure
    // that the size is enough to handle all filenames.
    //
    char filename[64];

    sprintf(filename, "%s.csv", argv[1]); // TODO something more secure than sprintf?    

    if((csv=fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL  )
    {
        printf("not found %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
```